# Broken Pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I've been slamming my head against a wall trying to figure this out but can't seem to get a solution. I have offset defined as 0 but in my pagination links offset+1 for older posts just leads to an error page. Not really sure where I'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is all the code from my page.php file...

```
<?php

$offset = $_GET['offset'] ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

$page_title = $wp_query->post->post_title;
$total_posts = wp_count_posts()->publish;

if ( $page_title == "Blog" ) {

?>
<div id="blog_content">
<?php
    if($_GET['message']){
        echo "<div style='background-color:#d9ffd1; padding:10px; margin-bottom:20px;'>".stripslashes($_GET["message"])."</div>";
    }
?>

<?php
    $post_count = 0;

    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'post_status' => "publish", "offset"=>$offset*10);
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); $post_count++; ?>
```

And then my pagination links

```
<div style="font-size:12px;">
        <div style="float:left; width:49%;">
        <?php
        the_post();

            if ($offset > 0): ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>&offset=<?=$offset-1?>">&larr; Newer Posts</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; width:49%; text-align: right;">
        <?php
        $next_post = get_next_post();
        if ($total_posts > $post_count + ($offset*10)): ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>&offset=<?=$offset+1?>">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why didn't you post this one to `http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/`

Comment: Need more information, what is the error page? what is the url of the error page?

Comment: Off-topic, belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. *sidenote:* why do you use single & double quotes in the same HTML ?

Comment: Did you look closely at pre_get_posts() and found_posts() function calls?  Check out `http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination`

Comment: What does this sentence mean?   `I have offset defined as 0 but in my pagination links offset+1 for older posts just leads to an error page.`  What exactly what, are you trying to achieve?  (Isn't offset = zero the default behavior here?  And doesn't  `get_option('posts_per_page');` work much easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not entirely clear on what you are trying to achieve, but I think you want to look closely at http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination

> Specifying hard-coded offsets in queries can and will break pagination
>   since offset is used by WordPress internally to calculate and handle
>   pagination.
>
> To get around this limitation, you will need to write some additional
>   code to manually handle pagination; you need to detect whether a loop
>   has additional pages and then dynamically calculate the appropriate
>   offset for the current page.

The code for controlling custom pagination will all occur within your functions.php file and not within the template page.php  You can set an initial offset, as well as redefine the number of posts per page.  There are specific samples displayed on the codex link above.

You will be adding the action before the query is run, via

```
   add_action('pre_get_posts', 'myprefix_query_offset', 1 );
```

and you will have to account for the customization via

```
   add_filter('found_posts', 'myprefix_adjust_offset_pagination', 1, 2 );
```